# mysqli_connect in a function throws error

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli

I'm sure the question is easy to answer, but I don't get it. 
When I try to connect in a function it throws me an "Access denied for user''@'localhost'" error. It looks like the array isn't available in the array, because the error says I didn't enter a username and password.

The code is:

```
$config["mysql_host"]   = "localhost";
$config["mysql_user"]   = "myusername";
$config["mysql_pass"]   = "mypass";
$config["db_name"]      = "mydb_name";
$config["event_tname"]  = "tablename";


function get_events(){ 
        $mysqli = mysqli_connect($config['mysql_host'], $config['mysql_user'], $config['mysql_pass'], $config["db_name"]); //connect to mysql and select the database

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$config["event_tname"]; //a simple query

        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die ("Error, please contact the provider!"/* . mysqli_error()*/); //execute

        while($all_events = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  //fetch and just print it
            foreach($all_events as $key => $val)
              echo($val." | ");
        }

        mysqli_free_result($result);} //END -- clear $result
events(); //just an example: call the function
```

What do I have to change at the array?

Regards,
Franz

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you should consider using mysqli object-orientated. There is no reason to use procedural style anymore.

Secondly global PHP variables are not available inside of functions, therefore you need to pass the array to the function as explained in the other answer.

See [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for more information on PHPs variable scope.

Imho the best solution would be to use a class for your application and store the config as private attributes. Methods of that class will then have access to the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

just add `global $config;` inside your function as

```
function get_events(){

   global $config;

        $mysqli = mysqli_connect($config['mysql_host'], $config['mysql_user'], $config['mysql_pass'], $config["db_name"]); //connect to mysql and select the database

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$config["event_tname"]; //a simple query

        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error());

        while($all_events = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  //fetch and just print it
            foreach($all_events as $key => $val)
              echo($val." | ");
        }

        mysqli_free_result($result);} //END -- clear $result
get_events(); //ju
```

or pass the config param to function

```
function get_events($config){ 

        $mysqli = mysqli_connect($config['mysql_host'], $config['mysql_user'], $config['mysql_pass'], $config["db_name"]); //connect to mysql and select the database

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$config["event_tname"]; //a simple query

        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error());

        while($all_events = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  //fetch and just print it
            foreach($all_events as $key => $val)
              echo($val." | ");
        }

        mysqli_free_result($result);} //END -- clear $result
get_events($config); //ju
```